# do different stack exchange sites have different rules regarding user banning

Tags: discussion

More curious than anything else and this is about Stack Exchange not SO. I know there's some unspoken rules regarding user banning based upon downvoting of questions. I'm curious whether different sites have different values for banning? I could imagine things like religion or politics migth get downvoted more (maybe, maybe not).

Maybe a corollary, do any of the stack exchange sites advocate opinion -  based answers? Perhaps history where everything is essentially opinion?

Comment: AFAIK the automatic quality ban is *off* by default on all sites, and has to be turned on manually if the site itself requests it. As far as different thresholds, I'm only aware of Meta (here) being harder to hit.